# Need a query to find the growth in revenue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody help me in writing the query to find the only Products where revenue growth happened. In this scenario, it should be `Toys` with all three years.

```
Products    Year      Revenue

Toys        2012       1000

Toys        2013       1500

Toys        2014       3000

Chocolates  2012       1000

Chocolates  2013        900

Chocolates  2014       1500

PlayingKit  2012       3000

PlayingKit  2013       1500

PlayingKit  2014       5000
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The following query containing two simple `self-joins` should work fine for what you want:

```
SELECT t2012.Products, t2012.Revenue Revenue2012, t2013.Revenue Revenue2013, t2014.Revenue Revenue2014 
FROM YourTable t2012
INNER JOIN YourTable t2013 ON t2013.Products = t2012.Products
INNER JOIN YourTable t2014 ON t2014.Products = t2012.Products
WHERE t2012.[Year] = 2012 AND t2013.[Year] = 2013 AND t2014.[Year] = 2014 AND t2014.Revenue > t2013.Revenue AND t2013.Revenue > t2012.Revenue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2008 or later, consider a recursive query using common table expressions (CTE), as [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
DECLARE @tblProducts TABLE  
    (
    ProductName varchar(100)
    , SalesYear INT
    , Revenue MONEY
    )

INSERT INTO @tblProducts
SELECT 'Toys'        ,2012       ,1000
UNION SELECT 'Toys'       , 2013       ,1500
UNION SELECT 'Toys'      ,  2014       ,3000
UNION SELECT 'Chocolates',  2012       ,1000
UNION SELECT 'Chocolates',  2013        ,900
UNION SELECT 'Chocolates',  2014       ,1500
UNION SELECT 'PlayingKit',  2012       ,3000
UNION SELECT 'PlayingKit',  2013       ,1500
UNION SELECT 'PlayingKit',  2014       ,5000

;WITH CTE_IsGrowthYear
AS
(
    --Anchor 
    SELECT 
        *,
        1 As IsGrowth
        FROM @tblProducts P
        WHERE P.SalesYear = 
            (SELECT MIN(SalesYear) FROM @tblProducts P2 WHERE P2.ProductName = P.ProductName)  --NOTE:  First year is always a growth year
    UNION ALL
    --Recursive
    SELECT P.*,
        1 As IsGrowth
        FROM CTE_IsGrowthYear IG
            INNER JOIN @tblProducts P
                ON IG.ProductName = P.ProductName
            WHERE IG.SalesYear = P.SalesYear - 1  --Next year after anchor or recursive year
            AND P.Revenue > IG.Revenue  --Did revenue grow in subsequent year?
)
SELECT 
    C.ProductName
    , T.CountYears --Years with recurring growth, every single year
    FROM CTE_IsGrowthYear C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT P.ProductName, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT SalesYear) as CountYears  --How many years are required for growth
                    FROM @tblProducts P
                    GROUP BY P.ProductName
            ) T --Total Number of Years             
            ON C.ProductName = T.ProductName
    GROUP BY C.ProductName, T.CountYears
    HAVING SUM(C.IsGrowth) = T.CountYears  --How many years had actual, recurring growth
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to derive results 1 column in 2 rows, the solution is to join the table to itself, "offset" to put both values on one row.

```
select b.Products, b.Year, b.Revenue,
       b.Revenue - a.revenue as Growth
from T as a join T as b
on a.Products = b.products
and a.Year + 1 = b.Year
where b.Revenue - a.revenue > 0
```